# Why my Delete function is not working properply?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, mern

So I'm almost complete on my MERN with Redux/Toolkit, I've done Create, Read, and Update. I can also delete a product, but it doesn't function the way I wanted to.

So what happen is, when I delete the **item1** It will delete the last row of the table.
in this image, I will try to delete the **item1**

[Before I click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBbfz.png)

After clicking the item1, it removes the item 3

[After I click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmXCl.png)

But when I refresh it, It corrects itself

[After refresh/reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j7yU.png)

apiCalls.js

```
export const deleteProduct = async (id, dispatch) => {
    dispatch(deleteProductStart());
    try {
      const res = await publicRequest.delete(`/products/${id}`);
      dispatch(deleteProductSuccess(res.data));
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch(deleteProductFailure());
    }
  };
```

MyProduct.js

```
const MyProducts = () => {
  const {products, isFetching, isError} = useSelector((state) => state.product)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    deleteProduct(id, dispatch);
  };

  useEffect(() =>{
    getProduct(dispatch);
  },[dispatch])

  return (
    <Box>
        <Navbar />
        <Box  sx={{display: {xs: 'none', md: 'flex'}, padding: '20px', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
          <Typography variant="h5" fontWeight={700}>My Products</Typography>
          <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table sx={{ minWidth: 600 }} aria-label="simple table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow bgcolor="skyblue">
              <TableCell align='center'>Product</TableCell>
              <TableCell align='center'>Image</TableCell>
              <TableCell align='center'>Price</TableCell>
              <TableCell align='center'>Action</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {products.map((product) => (
              <TableRow
                key={product._id}
              >
                <TableCell align='center' component="th" scope="row">{product.title}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align='center'><Box component="img" sx={{width: '80px', height: '80px', borderRadius: '10px', objectFit: 'contain'}} src={product.productImage}/></TableCell>
                <TableCell align='center'>Php {product.price}</TableCell> 
                <TableCell align='center' bgcolor="skyblue" >
                  <Box sx={{display: 'flex', alignItems:'center', justifyContent: 'center', gap: "10px"}}>
                      <Link to={`/editproduct/${product._id}`}>
                        <Button variant="contained">Edit</Button>
                      </Link>
                      <Button onClick={() => handleDelete(product._id)} color="error" variant="contained">Delete</Button>
                  </Box>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
        </Box>
      
    </Box>
  )
}
```

productSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const productSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'product',
    initialState: {
        products: [],
        isFetching: false,
        isError: false
    },
    reducers: {
            deleteProductStart: (state) => {
            state.isFetching = true
            state.isError = false
          },
          deleteProductSuccess: (state, action) => {
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.products.splice(
              state.products.findIndex((item) => item._id === action.payload),
              1
            );
          },
          deleteProductFailure: (state) => {
            state.isFetching = false
            state.isError = true
          },
      
    }
})

export const {   
    deleteProductStart,
    deleteProductSuccess,
    deleteProductFailure,

  } = productSlice.actions
  
  export default productSlice.reducer
```

Comment: What is the value of action.payload?

Answer (score 0):

```
deleteProductSuccess: (state, action) => {
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.products.splice(
              state.products.findIndex((item) => item._id === action.payload),
              1
            );
          },
```

In this code block you are finding product by index considering `action.payload` as item id. And you are passing data from response as action.

```
dispatch(deleteProductSuccess(res.data));
```

So `item._id === action.payload` will always fails. `findByIndex` will return `-1`. `splice(-1, 1)` will remove the last element.

1. Fixing the `action.payload` will fix this issue.
2. You have to consider the scenario when item not exist. Currently it is removing last item.